# Download content periodically in background ios 5

Tags: asynchronous, background, download, connection, task

Hi In my app I need to download new content every determined time while app is in background. I've been reading something about using NSOperation, async dispatch and using  beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler, but I haven't got this clearly and I don't know if I need to use some timer to have my app downloading content every hour for example.

Can anyone tell me what is the best way to achieve this? or at least point me to the right direction and what objects I need to use.

Thank you guys for your comments.

EDIT: Reading on the internet I found some guys saying that NSTimer is stopped when app enters the lock screen. is this true? How can I have my app downloading new content from a service every hour?, even if the app is in background and the device is in lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS your application can work in background only within some exceptions (like it is VoIP, location-based and some other ones) otherwise it will not be allowed to work in background.
Also, iOS can kill your app at any time just to save some memory.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've read. I need to download content such as news or articles to my app, I think there's no problem with that. So what's the way to do this? Should I use a NSTimer when app is in background and make the connection every determined time? How do I use ..taskWithExpirationHandler? Thanks!

Comment: This will not work in this way. Application will not work in background for hour or more. You can use push notifications or local notifications to show user that new article is available, and when user will open your application - download that article.